# django didn't filter datetime?

Tags: python, django

I have this code, And I found it didn't filter the date I want,

Here is my code:

```
today    = 2014-12-24 00:00:00+08:00  #<type 'datetime.datetime'>
tomorrow =  2014-12-25 00:00:00+08:00  #<type 'datetime.datetime'>

for i in Showtime.objects.filter(movie_id=movieid,theater_id=theaterid,datetime__range=(today,tomorrow)):
    print i
    if i.mvtype not in movietimes:
        movietimes[i.mvtype] = []
    movietimes[i.mvtype].append(i.movietime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
return movietimes
```

I print `i` to see what happened.and I found that it didn't filter the date right

```
2014-12-23 16:10:00+00:00
2014-12-24 09:00:00+00:00
2014-12-25 05:00:00+00:00
2014-12-23 06:50:00+00:00
2014-12-23 11:10:00+00:00
2014-12-23 13:20:00+00:00
2014-12-23 15:30:00+00:00
```

It should only show the date between 12-24 and 12-25 :

```
2014-12-23 16:10:00+00:00   (this +8 hr is 2014-12-24)
2014-12-24 09:00:00+00:00
```

Please help me thanks!!

Comment: Have you read the docs for `range`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
Showtime.objects.filter(movie_id=movieid,theater_id=theaterid,movietime__range=(today,tomorrow))
```

I guess?

Since your field name is `movietime`, syntax should be `movietime__range` for filtering.